# Decimal number format and region coding

Tags: lua, cygwin

I have lua program, that loads data from string. I need to convert those data to double, using [tonumber](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/tonumber). Problem is, that under cygwin in Windows 7, I got `nil`, if number contains `.` insetad of `,`. How to solve this ?

```
n = tonumber("7.5") -> gives nil
n = tonumber("7,5") -> gives 7.5
```

Comment: `s = "7.5"; n = tonumber((s:gsub("[.,]",tostring(1.5):sub(2,2))))`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: @Schollii - This is a solution, I think.  But I have not tested it.

Comment: You have to know several things about every string and text file; The binary representation is never enough. Short list: Character set, encoding, locale. If you know the locale then you use [lhf's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21798487/2226988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
old = os.setlocale("C")
n = tonumber("7.5")
os.setlocale(old)
```